# angular authentication with spring boot

Tags: angular, authentication, spring-boot, jwt

i 'm working on project using the angular 2 in the front end and symfony in the back and in another project i'm using angular 2 in the front end and spring in the back end .

i'm really blocked on how to manage sessions in the backend and frontend in the same time . in fact i'm using websrvice between the front end and the back end in the two project . and i'm asking on how to implement this authentication and managing sessions between the front end and the back end . i found nothing about that .

i 'm asking also if the angular cas for authentication is available for angular 2 because i found that the angular cas is working just for angularJs and i don't find something about angular cas in angular 2 .

i don't use firebase or auth0 or any other autorisation server . i want to use in local .
this is the architecture of my project :
[image: see the app architecture here]

some help please, i'm really blocked for the moment about those issues ,thank you in advance

Comment: You could use JWT or use the normal session with cookies and add spring session to make is scalable.

Comment: You should go through [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/). It explains some different patterns. It's for AngularJS (1), but the backend concepts still apply.

Comment: @peeskillet thank you for the tuto , but i'm using angular 2

Comment: for the JWT or normal session , can you show me some tuto for using the jwt or normal session with anguar 2

Comment: The backend concepts should still apply. Go through the tutorial and just copy and paste the angular code. The tutorial has complete examples on Github that it links to. The point is to learn the basic concepts for the backend part. It still applies if you are using Angular 2. It's a good learning process. The tutorial is very thorough. You can decide which way you want to do after reading the toturial. It might take a couple of days to go through the whole thing, but it is _very_ informative. It will explain using the normal session

Comment: i'll try ; thank you